# Quemar etiqueta [visual]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado, solicitud-de-lista-negra

De vez en cuando aparecen preguntas con la etiqueta [visual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual). En todos los casos, la intención en realidad es hacer referencia a *Visual Studio* o algún sabor de *Visual Basic*. A medida que los encuentro, los corrijo para usar la etiqueta adecuada.

Pero ya que la etiqueta [visual](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual) no me parece útil, propongo que se elimine y que se ponga en la lista negra.

Comment: *la lista negra*, quizas seria un problema si en un futuro saliera no digamos un lenguaje, sino una libreria relevante que adoptara ese nombre, de llevar ese tag como usted propone se tendria que tener encuenta si en un futuro apareciera algo con ese nombre. P.D: Pero que ami no me importa si se anula ese tag, simplemente era una observacion. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel llegado ese escenario, que creo que es muy poco probable, seguramente se podría especificar algo más que "visual" en el nombre, o, en su defecto, pedir que se revierta para permitirlo.

Comment: En paralelo estoy proponiendo [Quemar etiqueta \[studio\]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1740/127).

Comment: @Mariano ya solo lo comentaba por si algun dia, sucede que alguien dice que no puede poner el tag visual o algo asi, que sea mas facil, al haberse mencionado darse cuenta de donde podria estar el error, solo eso. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel entendí, y está muy bien la advertencia.

Comment: La etiqueta podría servir para preguntas que se traten de la generación de gráficos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### A favor

Esto es claramente un error de un usuario que intenta escribir `visual studio`, `visual basic`, `visual c++`, `visual fox pro` <sub><sup>(-no, no creo)</sup></sub>, o similares, con un espacio en el medio en vez de un guión.

Poner esta etiqueta en la lista negra ayudará a organizar mejor estas preguntas.

Comment: Esta etiqueta no existe dado a que se ha removido ya de todas las preguntas asociadas y el sistema la borro. Por eso puedo marcar esta solicitud cómo completada.