# Quemar etiqueta [studio]

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado, solicitud-de-lista-negra

Actualmente hay 12 preguntas etiquetadas [studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/studio).

Esta etiqueta se genera cuando un usuario intenta etiquetar con un espacio en vez de un guión:

- `android studio`, que corresponden a las 12 actuales (voy a corregirlas ahora).
- `visual studio`, que ya fueron reetiquetadas correctamente,
  y en paralelo se está solicitando [Quemar etiqueta [visual]](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1732/127).

#### Propongo quemar la etiqueta [studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/studio).

Poner esta etiqueta en la lista negra ayudará a organizar mejor estas preguntas, obligando a que el usuario lo corrija. Lo planteo como discusión por si hay algo que no esté considerando:

¿Les parece bien?

---

**Editado 17/4:** Viendo los votos `+10 | -0`, estoy reetiquetando de [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) a [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte)

Answer (score 1):

En el sentido que se le da en Meta ES a "[burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/burninate-request/info)", el "quemado" de la etiqueta de [studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/studio) ya debería tener [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado) ya que actualmente no hay ninguna pregunta con la etiqueta en cuestión.

Quedaría pendiente que se pusiera en la lista negra para evitar su reaparición.

Comment: Correcto. Probablemente deba reetiquetar. [Meta-tag:solicitud-de-lista-negra]?

Comment: @Mariano: No estoy seguro que en este sitio como comunidad queramos tener por separado el "quemado" del "destierro" (¿enegrecido? ¿etiqueta non-grata? ¿condenada al ostracismo?)

Comment: seguí la misma lógica de MSE al crear [meta-tag:solicitud-de-lista-negra], pero acepto cualquier propuesta para el uso de estas etiquetas

Comment: @Mariano: En MSE hay varias etiquetas con "blacklist", una se refiere a palabras, otra a etiqueta. Recién he propuesto una orientación de uso / wiki para [meta-tag:solicitud-de-lista-negra] bastante "comprensiva" (abarca "todo").

Comment: Actualmente [meta-tag:solicitud-de-quemado] abarca tanto la remoción como el "enegrecido" de la una etiqueta.

Answer (score 0):

No existe esta etiqueta. Se ha quitado de todas las preguntas en donde estaba asociada y después de 24 horas, fue eliminada por el sistema. Por eso puedo marcar esta petición cómo completada.